# MSGraph/Messages returns ldap-path? instead of actual address

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

So when parsing some emails I encountered this problem on emails sent to myself:

```
 var email_ids = await Graph
                .Users[user.Id]
                .MailFolders[SrcFolderId]
                .Messages.Request()
                .Select(x=> new { Id=x.Id,Subject = x.Subject,From = x.From,Received = x.ReceivedDateTime,Sender = x.Sender})
                .GetAsync();

                foreach (var msg in email_ids)
                {
                   var from = msg.From.EmailAddress.Address; 
                   //returns:"/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=A744B91971114B01B89FD0C4B28F412F-JANECKI MAR"
                }
```

On other emails the attribute works. bug or feature?

Comment: Does it happen in your developer tenant?

Comment: @user2250152 I dont have a developer tenant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange always stores email addresses in it's Native EX format and the Graph will generally resolve them (from the the directory eg AAD) when you make the query. However if the user has been deleted (or the mailbox has been migrated and the address is no longer valid) it can't resolve them anymore and will just return the native address. There are also some edge cases where this happens when you enumerate messages in those cases just doing a Get on the email id endpoint (/messsage/{id}) should work (but is really expensive in terms of throttling).

What i would suggest is if your always need the SMTP address is include https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagsendersmtpaddress-canonical-property in your query in the case you get a EX address returned then you will always have the SMTPaddress available without needing to make any extra queries. eg

```
           .Users[user.Id]
           .MailFolders[SrcFolderId]
           .Messages.Request()
           .Expand("singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x5D01')")
           .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Subject = x.Subject, From = x.From, Received = x.ReceivedDateTime, Sender = x.Sender, SingleValueExtendedProperties = x.SingleValueExtendedProperties})
           .GetAsync();
```

in v5 something like

```
        string selectList = "Id,Subject,From,ReceivedDateTime,Sender,SingleValueExtendedProperties";
        string exProp = "singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x5D01')";
        var messages = graphServiceClient.Users[userId].MailFolders["inbox"].Messages.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
        {
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { selectList };
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { exProp };
        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Value.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Subject = x.Subject, From = x.From, Received = x.ReceivedDateTime, Sender = x.Sender, SingleValueExtendedProperties = x.SingleValueExtendedProperties });
        foreach(var message in messages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.Sender);
        }
```

Comment: This was the solution thank you. I totally forgot that I sent this one email from my personal email account for testing purposes.

Comment: do you have a working solution for Microsoft.Graph 5.x.x?

Comment: I added a v5 sample that worked okay for me